# C# Class that can return or be multiple types of controls

Tags: c#, winforms

I am building a class that displays either a combobox or a listview (more to follow in the future). Part of the class is a list called OptionList that holds all the values. In the class are methods to update the list and read the list and set the displaystyle (combobox or listview). The List will be bound to either the combobox or the Listview. During runtime the displaystyle can be changed.

I am having a hard time figuring out what the best setup for this would be, should I add a Control member in the class that can be either the listview or the combobox or are there better ways to implement this?

In the calling class I simply want to show the control and update / read the list without worrying what the actual control is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be better thinking about the MVC pattern.  The "View" would be a wrapper around the particular control you are using.  The update methods could move to the controller and the raw data lives in the model.

Support for listview or combobox would be handled by different implementations of your view interface.

Comment: Thanks Graham, after reading up on MVC, that is actually exactly what I want to do :) Just wondering, my Model class would contain the definition of the individual items, but where should the list be placed that holds these individual items?